# NHibernate Multiple Criteria Difficulties

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having difficulties with multiple joins in the NHibernate Criteria search.  Say I had a pet table, and I wanted to return all pets where the pet category was Dog, and the owner gender was female, ordered by the pet birthday.  I've tried a bunch of permutations for how I can get this but haven't been able to figure it out.  My latest iteration is as follows:

```
var recentPets = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Pet))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("PetBirthday"))
            .CreateCriteria("PetType", "pt", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .CreateCriteria("PetOwnerId", "po", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Add(Expression.Eq("pt.PetTypeName", petType))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("po.PersonGender", gender))
            .List<Pet>();
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Try moving the pt.PetTypeName line up one, just under the join for that table.  It's hard for me to help more without more information.  You should look at the SQL that is being generated to see if it's obvious from that what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are not using the Hibernate/Java persistence query language to perform the query?

```
select p from Pet p
join p.owner o
where o.gender = :gender
and p.type.name = :petType
order by p.birthday
```